# How do I compare current time to a preset time in PHP?

Tags: php, string, date, time

I want PHP to check if it's 8:30 AM and if it is, I want it to change a variable.
I tried,

```
$eightthirtyam = "08:30:00";
if(time() >= strtotime($eightthirtyam )){
    $refresh = true;
}
```

But the boolean doesn't change. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: if(date("H:i") == "08:30") ...

Comment: logic don't seems have any fault.  check by `var_dump(time());`  and `var_dump (strtotime($eightthirtyam ));` and see why your logic failed.It's because of timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime` depends on the time zone.. so you should define timezone too.
You should set your default timezone before comparing.

http://php.net/strtotime

Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$eightthirtyam = "08:30:00";
if(time() >= strtotime($eightthirtyam )){
    $refresh = true;
}
```

http://codepad.org/GC0VA7nw

Comment: Isn't the default timezone automatically identified from the servers timezone? Do I have to set it manually??

Comment: No it doesn't work like that.. The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC) (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#100220).... while strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp.... so you should set default time zone in your code itself

Comment: It actually did. Thanks

Comment: List of Supported Timezones : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.... You might need this..

Answer (score 1):

The function `time()` returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC), while `strtotime()` give a local time, So there is a timezone offset.

You need to subtract the timezone offset form the local time, before the compare, and check the [live demo](https://eval.in/813003) for a good understanding.

Comment: reasons for downvote will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In php we have `new DateTime` function. So you can use this to match your date as give below example

```
$refresh = false;
$eightthirtyam = "08:30:00";
$date = new DateTime();
if($date->format('H:i:s') == $eightthirtyam)
{
    $refresh = true;
}
```

Here is an example

```
$refresh = "false";
$eightthirtyam = "08:30:00";
$date = new DateTime("2017-06-07 8:30:00"); // suppose your system current time is this.
if($date->format('H:i:s') == $eightthirtyam)
{
    $refresh = "true";
}
echo $refresh;
```

You can check answer by executing on online php editor `http://www.writephponline.com/`

Try above example, I think this may help you.

Comment: I tried this but the it still doesn't work. I tried using this with 
if($date->format('H:i:s') >= $eightthirtyam)
Or else the time would have to be exactly 8:30:00 to test, but it still wouldn't run.

Comment: @DaveHowson just checked and working fine.. FYI: `new DateTime();` current date time of system. if your current system date time is not 8:30 then this will give you $refresh as false answer. I'm updating my answer with an example. you can check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$eightthirtyam = "08:30:00";
$refresh = false;
if(strtotime(date('H:i:s') == strtotime($eightthirtyam )){
    $refresh = true;
}
```

Reference:-/ [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$hr= date('H:i'); 

  if(strtotime($hr)==strtotime(08:30)  ){
    $refresh = true;
  }
```

Please try this way. It will work i your case.

Answer (score -1):

the code is fine untill i know. but still if you want to do some actions, you can do something like this.

```
         $refresh=false;
         $eightthirtyam = "08:30:00";
         if(time() >= strtotime($eightthirtyam ))
         {
          $refresh = true;
         }
         if($refresh)
         {
            //your statement is true do something here
         }
         else
         {
           //false statement
         }
```